# google oauth how to get the "code" from step2 url

Tags: python, django, api, oauth

I am trying to authenticate using Google OAuth but am having a little trouble following the tutorial.

Here is my current setup:

```
    FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id='67490467925.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        client_secret='K1tkrPK97B2W16ZGY',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        user_agent='Real_Hub/1.0',
        redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/',)


    storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
        auth_uri = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return auth_uri
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)

        service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
                        developerKey='AIzaSyCBGjIQ2uNbThW_2oMO9P-Ufb8kc')

        return service
        #End OAUTH...
```

I am unsure where I should put `credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)` and `storage.put(credentials)` and how do I get the "code" variable? In the API it says from the redirect url. But I do not follow how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a method for handling callbacks from the OAuth provider, then map that callback method to a url on your application, something like

```
  http://yourserver/auth_callback
```

Then set the `redirect_uri` to the `auth_callback` url when you create the Flow class

```
  FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='67490467925.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    ...
    redirect_uri='http://yourserver/auth_callback')
```

After you get the `auth_uri`, you need to redirect the user to that uri so they can authenticate/authorize

```
  self.redirect(auth_uri, ...)
```

After authentication/authorization, OAuth provider will "call you back" to the redirect_uri you specified earlier. In your callback handler method, you will now parse for `code` or if it's not present, check for `error` parameter

```
  code = self.request.get("code")
  credentials = FLOW.step2_exchange(code)
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this, and I haven't worked with python in awhile so syntax may be off, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: I just went ahead and read the API again and figured it out, but this answer is correct (: thank you.

Comment: What is self in this answer?